# Background image doesn't change for each slide

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations, pseudo-class

I'm making a slideshow for my website, but when I try to put a link on them (all 6 of them have to have a link its one of the requirements for the site), I just get the same image repeated over and over again. When I remove the  and  tags it doesn't happen anymore.

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

#slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 510px;
  width: 728px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slide-wrapper {
  width: 4368px;
  -webkit-animation: slide 25s ease infinite;
}

.slide {
  float: left;
  height: 510px;
  width: 728px;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(../site/fotos/muhammad\ ali.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(../site/fotos/muhammad\ ali\ 2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(../site/fotos/muhammad\ ali\ 3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url(../site/fotos/muhammad\ ali\ 4.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide:nth-child(5) {
  background-image: url(../site/fotos/muhammad\ ali\ 5.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide:nth-child(6) {
  background-image: url(../site/fotos/muhammad\ ali\ 6.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  10% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: -728px;
  }
  28% {
    margin-left: -728px;
  }
  36% {
    margin-left: -1456px;
  }
  44% {
    margin-left: -1456px;
  }
  52% {
    margin-left: -2184px;
  }
  60% {
    margin-left: -2184px;
  }
  68% {
    margin-left: -2912px;
  }
  76% {
    margin-left: -2912px;
  }
  84% {
    margin-left: -3640px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -3640px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="slide-wrapper">
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So it just keeps on repeating the same photo, even when I put in different links.

Comment: Add **.slide** class to <a> tag, and  then edit css to be: 
.slide:nth-child(N) div{...}

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue?

Comment: yeah, sorry i forgot to thank you but it worked! Thanks

Comment: @Morrismario if it solved the issue, please make sure to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You take class slide individually for each **slide**, so what happened here is always the first child, you need to change CSS like below

```
.slide-wrapper a:nth-child(1) .slide {
    background-image: url(https://wallpapercave.com/wp/1Odq43G.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.slide-wrapper a:nth-child(2) .slide {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/48/5/jR1olt.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.slide-wrapper a:nth-child(3) .slide {
    background-image: url(../site/fotos/muhammad\ ali\ 3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.slide-wrapper a:nth-child(4) .slide {
    background-image: url(../site/fotos/muhammad\ ali\ 4.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide-wrapper a:nth-child(5) .slide {
    background-image: url(../site/fotos/muhammad\ ali\ 5.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide-wrapper a:nth-child(6) .slide {
    background-image: url(../site/fotos/muhammad\ ali\ 6.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

so the best practice is you take a common class like above
just replace your slider image CSS with this

Comment: so exactly my answer 20 minutes after? why not upvote the answer already given?

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because `.slide` is always the first (and only) child of the `a` link, so you need to do this instead:

```
a:nth-child(N) .slide  { background-image: url('linkimage'); }
```

Snippet

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

#slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 510px;
  width: 728px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slide-wrapper {
  width: 4368px;
  -webkit-animation: slide 25s ease infinite;
}

.slide {
  float: left;
  height: 510px;
  width: 728px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

a:first-child .slide {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/510/718?random=1);
}

a:nth-child(2) .slide {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/510/718?random=2);
}

a:nth-child(3) .slide {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/510/718?random=3);
}

a:nth-child(4) .slide {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/510/718?random=4);
}

a:nth-child(5) .slide {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/510/718?random=5);
}

a:nth-child(6) .slide {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/510/718?random=6);
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  10% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: -728px;
  }
  28% {
    margin-left: -728px;
  }
  36% {
    margin-left: -1456px;
  }
  44% {
    margin-left: -1456px;
  }
  52% {
    margin-left: -2184px;
  }
  60% {
    margin-left: -2184px;
  }
  68% {
    margin-left: -2912px;
  }
  76% {
    margin-left: -2912px;
  }
  84% {
    margin-left: -3640px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -3640px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="slide-wrapper">
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
    <a link href="">
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```